# Vim return the cursor to the same point in the file when the buffer is written

Tags: macos, vim

The cursor is bouncing to the top of the file, but should be Returning to same point, in file, when the buffer is written? 
can any one see where i am going wrong?

```
function! ResCur() 
  if line("'\"") <= line("$")
    normal! g`"          
    return 1
  endif
endfunction

augroup resCur      
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWriteCmd * call ResCur()
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should probably quote [Vim FAQ](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/vimfaq2html3.pl#5.5):

> How do I configure Vim to open a file at the last edited location?
>
> Vim stores the cursor position of the last edited location for each
>   buffer in the '"' register. You can use the following autocmd in your
>   .vimrc or .gvimrc file to open a file at the last edited location:
>
> ```
> au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
>                      \ exe "normal g'\"" | endif
> ```
>
> For more information, read
>
> ```
> :help '"
> :help last-position-jump
> ```

Event, which triggers a call, is where problem lies. BufWriteCmd is used more to modify the behavior of write operations. But you would like to change how a file is loaded into a buffer. In this case BufReadPost, which is queued whenever an existing file is loaded into a new buffer.

Comment: To check if the ` '" ` mark is set you can use the example from the doc `au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g\`\"" | endif` which does the same but with an additionnal check.